# Do people work with FPGAs for a living?

Tags: fpga

As a student, I've been working with FPGAs in a physics laboratory setting for a while now, and I was wondering if there are careers based on FPGAs and their applications.

If not, is experience with FPGAs simply a nice, bonus skill to have when applying to jobs as an electrical engineer?

Comment: Nobody correctly uses FPGAs when they have a choice.  Plenty of people use FPGA's because there are no suitable options for the unique thing they want to do... but those are mostly high-price or experimental applications.  They are relatively rare in consumer products, though it is not entirely unheard of to use one as an interface between the stable part of a design and one which must adapt quickly to market changes.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Apple Macbook's and Google glass both contain FPGAs. As do some Samsung smartphones. Granted the are low power and low performance versions of the massively powerful cousins, but they are FPGAs none-the-less. But I agree, for many consumer applications an ARM processor, or MCU is sufficient. FPGAs really hold their own in massive data applications (radar, ultrasound, space, etc.) which are not really consumer application areas.

Comment: I am one of those people who use FPGAs on a day to day basis for my job.  I have designed several products that use FPGAs.  I consider digital logic a fundamental EE skill and ask related interview questions when hiring people.  Even if you only use MCUs in embedded systems and scoff at FPGAs the skill set used in FPGA/digital design will make you a better EE.  You will likely have a better understanding of what's going on under the hood of the MCU you're using (and potentially therefore use it better/smarter) if you have spent time designing digital systems.

Comment: @TomCarpenter - I've shipped FPGA products, but at the high-price/low-volume point.  Most consumer-oriented things anticipate enough volume for a stable design that for something a stored-program computer can't do, the NRE of an ASIC is worthwhile. FPGAs get the niche applications where it isn't.

Comment: @Tom - I suggest you may wish to flag for reopening?

Comment: @ChrisStratton  - I suggest you may wish to flag for reopening?

Comment: @Doov - I suggest you may wish to flag for reopening?

Comment: No, because it is not a valid question for the purposes of this site.

Comment: I can't resist -- it's less working with FPGAs for a living, and more being abused by FPGAs for a living. :)

Answer (score 3):

FPGAs are vital components both in the development processes and as components in end products in their own rights.

They are not just toys.

I once worked with an internet content filtering system which had at its core a bank of up to 16 Xilinx FPGAs for parallel processing and filtering of internet content. The 'program' of the FPGAs was uploaded by the host computer to keep fingerprints and suchlike up to date.

FPGSs are also used extensively for prototyping and proof of concept designs in chip manufacturing. Custom chip designs for customers will often be first designed by the customer on an FPGA and then reimplemented by the silicon house as an ASIC or similar.

So yes, there is a place in real industries for FPGAs, and having those skills can be essential for some job applications.

Comment: You may wish to flag for reopening?

Answer (score 2):

Designing FPGA logic well requires specialized skill and knowledge, so of course there are people who have acquired that skill and knowledge and make a living from it.

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot of career prospect with FPGA's. They're used a lot in digital logic design for instance, rather than go through the process of building a digital logic IC design for prototyping, they'll simulate it on an FPGA. There's quite a few other fields that use FPGA's as well, like UAV navigation. Mainly jobs with low volume, experimental design will be using them.